# Find the Harmonic Mean

Tags: statistics, summation

The question:

> Peter drives to work, a distance of 50 miles, at a speed of 75 mph and
>   returns home at a speed of 80 mph. What is his average speed for the round trip?

The formula to use here is the harmonic mean formula which is

$$n\over ∑{1\over x}$$

I am lost on how to set this up. I tried it this way $$50 miles\over ∑ ({1\over 75mph})+({1\over 80mph})$$ but clearly I got the answer wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Harmonic Mean $H$ is defined as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean): $$H=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}}$$

Your mistake, which is an easy one to make, is that the numerator in $H$ should be $n$ (specifically 2), and not '50 miles'.

(Edit: The mean average speed will be $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$ i.e. $\frac{75+85}{2}=80$ and the Harmonic mean average will be $\frac{2}{\frac{1}{75}+\frac{1}{85}}=79.6875$)

Comment: "Average speed" usually refers to the harmonic mean, as that is (total distance)/(total time).

Comment: I've clearly distinguished between Harmonic and usual mean. Both are averages of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

n is 2 in this case.  the number of $x$'s you are averaging.

Comment: Thanks.. I see that now :)